# UI automation with excel

Tags: excel, user-interface, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, vba

I am new to UI Automation. In my current organisation I was tasked with making an automated tool using GUI(Graphics User Interface) screen reading, but it is not working perfectly with other my colleague's machine because of a difference in screen resolution.

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANTIGgs7YM4&t=1s) link on you-tube to try and understand UI Automation with excel, but I can't find much on this topic anywhere else.

Can anyone direct me toward resources on UI Automation? I Would like to know where I can learn it, read about it, and how to implement it with Excel.

Thanks in advance I really appreciate if anyone could help me.

Comment: This is not a very precise question as far as I am concerned.
Have a look [at MSDN UI Automation overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIAutomation from Microsoft is very powerfull and works well with windows 7, 8, 10 also from visual basic for applications (32 and 64 bits) and can be handy used to do some nice GUI Automation without expensive tools.

Make sure in VBA reference you have UIAutomationCore.Dll references (and weird enough sometimes on some computers you have to copy this to your documents folder)

Below you can see 2 base examples but as MS Automation is a huge library for all routines you can read a lot on MSDN for full documentation.
I use the MS UIA routines in AutoIt and in VBA

- For AutoIt its shared over here

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/

- For VBA I do not have a standard library but someone did a try with
  this
  https://github.com/mhumpher/UIAutomation_VBA

Option Explicit

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As New CUIAutomation
    Dim oDesktop As IUIAutomationElement

    Set oDesktop = c.GetRootElement

    Debug.Print oDesktop.CurrentClassName & vbTab & oDesktop.CurrentName & vbTab & oDesktop.CurrentControlType

End Sub

'Test uia just dumps all windows of the desktop to the debug window
Sub testUIA()
    Dim allEl As IUIAutomationElementArray                  'Returns an element array with all found results
    Dim oElement As IUIAutomationElement                    'Reference to an element
    Dim ocondition As IUIAutomationCondition

    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As New clsUIA


    'Just reference the three mainly used properties. many more are available when needed
    Debug.Print x.oDesktop.CurrentName & x.oDesktop.CurrentClassName & x.oDesktop.CurrentControlType

    Set ocondition = x.oCUIAutomation.CreateTrueCondition             'Filter on true which means get them all
    Set allEl = x.oDesktop.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, ocondition)    'Find them in the direct children, unfortunately hierarchies are strange sometimes

    'Just reference the three mainly used properties. many more are available when needed
    For i = 0 To allEl.Length - 1
        Set oElement = allEl.GetElement(i)
        ' If oElement.CurrentClassName = "PuTTY" Then
          Debug.Print oElement.CurrentClassName & oElement.CurrentName & oElement.CurrentControlType
           ' Debug.Print oElement.CurrentBoundingRectangle

            oElement.SetFocus
            DoEvents
            Sleep 2000
       ' End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide us with "clsUIA" class?

Comment: That would be a classmodule named clsUIA with some  logic like Dim c As New CUIAutomation function oDesktop return c.getrootelement end function

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you provide with the whole code in separate answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are doing the automation using the coordinates, which changes when you switch to other resolution. If this is the case, please automate your application using ID, Class, Xpath, CSS etc. This link will help you in that: http://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html

For automation using Excel, please look into the following link:
http://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html

Comment: The OP asks to implement this process in Excel, which implies to me that they are wanting to automate applications that are not necessarily HTML.  My understanding is that Selenium is designed for interacting with HTML applications.  Can Selenium interact with Windows objects that are not HTML?

Answer (score 1):

create clsUIA class  then insert this code
'clsUIA with some logic like

```
'start by add the following code
Dim  c As New CUIAutomation
Public oCUIAutomation As New CUIAutomation
Function oDesktop() As IUIAutomationElement
Set oDesktop = c.GetRootElement
End Function
```