# How to change printer dialog default name in VBA? (when using the handle of the printer dialog)

Tags: vba, winapi, printing

I've obtained some data from dialog of SAP software and then I've pressed Print button in order to print the data. Then PRINT window appeared:

1. I've handled it into hWnd variable (please find in LINE 1 comment);
2. Then I want to change default printer name into "Microsoft Print to PDF" (I don't know how to change it);
3. Then I've pressed button OK (please find LINE 4 comment);

Here's the code:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
'''
 hWnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Print")  'LINE 1 comment;
 Childhwnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, ByVal 0&, "Button", "OK")';
'ON THIS LINE NEED TO INSERT CODE THAT CHANGES PRINTER NAME;
 SendMessage Childhwnd, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0& 'LINE 4 comment;
```

Please help me to change printer name.

Comment: Please notice that my PRINT window looks like in this image:https://www.google.ro/search?q=printer+dialog&rlz=1C1GGRV_enCH772CH772&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUgKCjm9_YAhWIjCwKHVzzCg4Q_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=yOnigS8PeId84M:

Comment: Can you set the default printer before you pull up dialog box, then change it back? Might be a little easier.

Comment: There is a lot of valuable information in this article: http://www.lessanvaezi.com/changing-printer-settings-using-the-windows-api/

Comment: UI Automation is best done using UI Automation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502092/1889329) for sample code. There are many benefits in using UI Automation. For one, the code won't break if run on a system, where the button isn't titled *"OK"* (e.g. on a Russian system). There's also no reason ever to call the ANSI versions of the Windows API. Just use the Unicode versions, and you won't have to convert between character sets up to 4 times per API call.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED (for Windows 10):
Please notice that the code which was needed is:

```
'Declarations
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
    Dim i                          'index to the selected item
    Dim getPrintName As String     ' the text of the selected item
    Dim getPrintNameLength As Long ' the length of the selected item's text
    Dim printPDFFound As Boolean
    Dim ChildhwndPrint11 As Long
    Dim ChildhwndPrint1 As Long
    Dim ChildhwndPrint As Long
    Dim hwndPrint As Long
    Const GW_CHILD = 5
    Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
    Const CB_GETLBTEXTLEN = &H149
    Const CB_GETLBTEXT = &H148

     getPrintName = Space(20)


    'Code Between Previous Lines LINE1 and LINE4 Used To Change The Print Name 

hwndPrint = hwnd
        ChildhwndPrint = GetWindow(hwndPrint, GW_CHILD)
        If ChildhwndPrint = 0 Then
            MsgBox "ChildhwndPrint not found."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ChildhwndPrint1 = GetWindow(ChildhwndPrint, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        If ChildhwndPrint1 = 0 Then
            MsgBox "ChildhwndPrint1 not found."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ChildhwndPrint11 = GetWindow(ChildhwndPrint1, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        If ChildhwndPrint11 = 0 Then
            MsgBox "ChildhwndPrint11 not found."
            Exit Sub
        End If

Call SendMessage(ChildhwndPrint11, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, True, 0)

    i = 0
            printPDFFound = False
            'getPrintName = ""
            Do Until (i = 30) Or (getPrintName = "Microsoft Print to PDF")
                    Call SendMessage(ChildhwndPrint11, CB_SETCURSEL, i, 0)
                    'Call SendMessage(ChildhwndPrint11, CB_GETLBTEXT, 2, buffer)
                    getPrintNameLength = SendMessage(ChildhwndPrint11, CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, ByVal CLng(i), ByVal CLng(0))
                    getPrintName = Space(getPrintNameLength) & vbNullChar
                    getPrintNameLength = SendMessage(ChildhwndPrint11, CB_GETLBTEXT, ByVal CLng(i), ByVal getPrintName)
                    getPrintName = Left(getPrintName, getPrintNameLength)
                    'MsgBox getPrintName
                    If getPrintName = "Microsoft Print to PDF" Then
                        printPDFFound = True
                    End If
                    i = i + 1
            Loop
            If printPDFFound = False Then
                MsgBox "<Microsoft Print to PDF> print name was not found."
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

Explaining the CODE:
I supposed that they can be maximum of 30 printers:

- I've searched for the handler of the print-name drop-down= ChildhwndPrint11 (I've used a Visual Studio Tool named Spy++, separately for my macro, and this tool shows all childs of open windows on desktop) [also, please find above standard declarations in Windows API Viewer for MS Excel x64, I,ve downloaded it from the Internet)
- I've showed the drop-down with CB_SHOWDROPDOWN
- so I looped until meeting the maximum printer (until 30 printer) or loop until print name is "Microsoft Print to PDF"
- I used scroll down drop down list that contains printer names
- for every CURSEL (element from drop-down list), I extracted printer name and printer length name
- if printer is found, I set printPDFFound to TRUE