# How to get Node item captions from TreeView embedded in external system?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I have a requirement to go through items from treeview control in external system via win32 API in VBA code, with the help of Spy++. I can tell the classname of the control is SysTreeView32.

Take Win-7 explorer as an example, on the left hand of the explorer, that is the control of treeview, I manage to go through all of its items with API sendmessage, but fail to get details of each item.

As for my codes, the line `result = SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_GETITEMA, False, ByVal vPointer)` returns 0. That may be the root cause.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Source As Long, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessID As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function TerminateProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal uExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function VirtualAllocEx Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpAddress As Any, ByRef dwSize As Long, ByVal flAllocationType As Long, ByVal flProtect As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function VirtualFreeEx Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpAddress As Any, ByRef dwSize As Long, ByVal dwFreeType As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WriteProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Long, llpBufferfer As Any, ByVal nSize As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Const TVGN_ROOT = &H0     
Private Const TVGN_CHILD = &H4   
Private Const TVGN_Next = &H1     
Private Const TVGN_Caret = &H9  

Private Const TVGN_Previous = &H2       
Private Const TVGN_Parent = &H3          
Private Const TVGN_FirstVisible = &H5   
Private Const TVGN_NextVisible = &H6     
Private Const TVGN_PreviousVisible = &H7  
Private Const TVGN_LastVisible = &H10

Private Const TVGN_DropHilite = &H8   

Private Const TV_FIRST = &H1100
Private Const TVM_GETITEMRECT  As Long = (TV_FIRST + 4)
Private Const TVM_GETNEXTITEM As Long = (TV_FIRST + 10)
Private Const TVM_SELECTITEM As Long = (TV_FIRST + 11)
Private Const TVM_DELETEITEM As Long = (TV_FIRST + 1)
Private Const TVM_GETCOUNT = (TV_FIRST + 5)

Private Const TVM_HITTEST = (TV_FIRST + 17)
Private Const TVM_GETITEM = (TV_FIRST + 12)
Private Const TVM_GETITEMA = (TV_FIRST + 12)
Private Const TVM_GETITEMW = (TV_FIRST + 62)

Private Const TVHT_ONITEMLABEL = &H4
Private Const TVIF_TEXT = &H1
Private Const GMEM_FIXED = &H0
Private Const TVM_EXPAND As Long = &H1102
Private Const WM_SETREDRAW As Long = &HB

Private Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF
Private Const MEM_DECOMMIT = &H4000
Private Const MEM_RELEASE = &H8000
Private Const MEM_COMMIT = &H1000
Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = &H40
Private Const MAX_LVMSTRING As Long = 255
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Private Type TVITEM
        mask As Long
        HTreeItem As Long
        state As Long
        stateMask As Long
        pszText As Long
        cchTextMax As Long
        iImage As Long
        iSelectedImage As Long
        cChildren As Long
        lParam As Long
End Type

Sub test2()
    Dim Flag As Long 
    Dim hTreeView As Long  
    Dim hTVRoot As Long
    Dim hTVItem As Long 

    Dim vProcessId As Long
    Dim vProcess As Long
    Dim vPointer As Long
    Dim vItemCount As Long
    Dim pMyItemMemory  As Long

    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As Long
    Dim bytes As Long
    Dim vItem As TVITEM
    Dim tmpItem As TVITEM
    Dim strBuffer()         As Byte
    Dim tmpString As String
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ReDim strBuffer(MAX_LVMSTRING)
    hTreeView = 1379188 'Handle by SPY++

    Call GetWindowThreadProcessId(hTreeView, vProcessId)
    vProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, vProcessId)
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    hTVRoot = SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_ROOT, ByVal 0&)         
    hTVItem = SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_CHILD, ByVal hTVRoot)   

    SendMessage hTreeView, TVM_SELECTITEM, TVGN_Caret, ByVal hTVItem 
    Flag = SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_EXPAND, TVM_EXPAND, ByVal hTVRoot) 

    vPointer = VirtualAllocEx(vProcess, ByVal 0&, 4096, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)

    With vItem
            .mask = TVIF_TEXT
            .HTreeItem = hTVItem
            .pszText = vPointer
        .cchTextMax = MAX_LVMSTRING
    End With

    result = WriteProcessMemory(vProcess, ByVal vPointer, vItem, LenB(vItem), 0)
    result = SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_GETITEMA, False, ByVal vPointer)
    result = ReadProcessMemory(vProcess, ByVal vPointer, strBuffer(0), LenB(tmpItem), 0)
    tmpString = StrConv(strBuffer, vbUnicode)

    Call VirtualFreeEx(vProcess, vPointer, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
    Call CloseHandle(vProcess)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I need to compare with the caption of each subitem from treeview control and desired words, going through all subitems and stop when matched, then select that subitem

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I had already get the the handle of the childnode by these two lines:     hTVRoot = SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_ROOT, ByVal 0&)         
    hTVItem = SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_CHILD, ByVal hTVRoot)  ,  but for my question, what I really want is the caption of the childnode

Comment: Stop using this brittle code and use the [UI automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) that is designed for such tasks. You will find [VBA samples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44756042/7571258) too.