# How to automate the login page using VBA code as shown in shared image

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I need to automate a workflow in which I need to login in an Addin. In this addin there is a login button, on which I need to click so that a Login Pop-up should get appeared. After this I need to enter username and password. Then in last clicking on proceed button.

I tried using "SetCursorPos" for click event but with entering text part it is not working for me.

I also tried using "FindWindow" and "SendMessage" api for handling pop-ups but I do not have access of SPY++ to know class name of application
Then to know class name I used "WindowFromPoint"/"GetCursorPos"/"GetClassName"

```
Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" (ByVal xPoint As Long, ByVal yPoint As Long) As Long
Private Type POINTAPI
X As Long
Y As Long
End Type
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long



Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
Label3.Caption = "KeyCode = " & KeyCode
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
SetWindowPos Me.hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
Timer1.Interval = 100
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Dim b As POINTAPI
Dim r, s, t As String
GetCursorPos b
Label1.Caption = "Mouse Position =" & " { " & b.X & " , " & b.Y & " }"
r = WindowFromPoint(b.X, b.Y)
t = Space(128)
s = GetClassName(r, t, 128)
Label2.Caption = "ClassName = " & t
End Sub
```

But still facing issues in Label1.Caption or sometimes getting error on b.X or b.Y.

I tried so many times but still not getting result.

[image]

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is for automating UIs.

Comment: Okay got it., but can you provide me some sample in VBA coding for UI automation. This will help me a lot .

Comment: [UI automation with excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44756042/1889329) should get you started.